# Let's rename computer-science to it-slang

Tags: discussion, tagging, proposal

So, as of today, there exists 3 questions tagged `computer-science`, to be precise:

- [Idiomatic translation of "Debug"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/297/idiomatic-translation-of-debug)
- [Established translation for “Application crash”?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/318/established-translation-for-application-crash)
- [English to Russian Computer-science / Programming dictionary](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/319/english-to-russian-computer-science-programming-dictionary)

At least first two questions actually are not about computer science, they are about **it slang**, these are quite different things. You see, computer science is a theoretical discipline, a cousin of mathematics. Here is StackExchange site on [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com) topic.

I can imagine that once such kind of questions, questions on CS terminology will be asked here, but now it is not the case.

So, I think the best will be to rename computer-science to "it slang" or something. Who is with me? )))

Comment: If such a change were made, I think it should be IT-slang, not it-slang. When I first read the title of the question I thought the prefix "it" was the word "it" and the title didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

All tags here imply "`$TAGNAME` in Russian language" (otherwise the question tagged would be an offtopic itself).

English.SE uses "internet" and "programming" for internet-related and programming-related slangs. Probably we should do the same (as computer science is not anything that pops up into one's head first when tagging).

Comment: well, I disagree, programming is not as good as  "IT slang". `Холодный контент` is definitely an IT term, but we hardly can call it programming, and even not all such term are related to internet at all. On the other hand, I can imagine an internet-related term which have nothing to do with neither programming nor IT - say, meme-related staff, for example.

Comment: @shabunc: what I wanted to say is that we shoudn't add "slang" to each tag. However, of the three questions you mention, two are definitely "programming" and the third I've just closed as an offtopic :)

Comment: > what I wanted to say is that we shoudn't add "slang" to each tag. - cannot get this point. Does "IT terminology" sounds more plausible? )))

Comment: @shabunc: this site is about Russian language. When we tag a question "IT" or "computer" or whatever this already means "Russian IT language" or "Russian computer slang".

Comment: so, finally, what's the output of this discussion. As far as I've understand, it is indeed better to rename this tag to programming.

Comment: @shabunc Yes, I think, it is, but if you want to use the programming tag, write a wiki there so that people could use it the way we planned =)